# "Second order neighbourhood" $n$ color theorem. What is $n$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, reference-request, soft-question

The [four color theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) for coloring maps is a well known theorem that was proven in the 1970s with help of computers.

---

It basically means that if you draw any map on a sheet of paper, no matter how the areas are divided if you have to color all areas, you can be sure to not have to paint two neighbouring areas with the same color if you use at least 4 colors. 4 is the smallest number of colors that you would need to be sure to avoid coloring two neighbouring areas in the same color.

---

Do there exist any similar result for how many colors one must have if one was to paint a map where a country and neither its neighbours or the **neighbours of its neighbours** are allowed to share the same color?

---

**Edit** you are allowed to introduce variables to derive expressions of $n$ in.

Comment: Some constraints will be necessary. If a country has $n$ neighbors, all of them must have different colors.

Comment: @PerManne : Yes the largest number of neighbours any country has will be a lower limit of the number of colors in our problem. But maybe more limits will be required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to finding the chromatic number of the square of a planar graph.

This seems to be an open problem. See first paragraph and Conjecture 1 in this [arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06504).

---

Perhaps an explicit answer would help. The 4 Color Theorem states that no more than 4 colors are required to color the regions of a map such that adjacent regions get assigned different colors, regardless of the number of regions in the map. Now, if we add the restriction that any region must be assigned a color that is distinct from the color assigned to the neighbors of its neighbors too, then it is not (yet) known if such bound exists.

There is a conjecture (Wegner's Conjecture) regarding the number of colors required in this situation. The conjectured bound depends on the maximum number of regions that a region shares a boundary with on the given map, let us call this quantity $\Delta$. Wegner's conjecture states the following.

1. If no region shares a boundary with more than three other regions ($\Delta\leq 3$), then the map can be colored with at most 7 colors.
2. If $4\leq\Delta\leq7$, then $\Delta+5$ colors are enough.
3. If $\Delta\geq 8$, then $\lceil\frac{3\Delta}{2}\rceil+1$ colors suffice.

Seems like in the linked preprint above they prove that case 1 is in fact true.

Comment: Okay that sounds interesting, but I am not well versed enough in graph theory to make sense of it right now. Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: @mathreadler: answer has been updated, hope it is a bit more helpful.
Feel free to accept the post if it answered your question.

Comment: I think W's claim is that $\lfloor 3\Delta/2\rfloor +1$ colors suffice.

Comment: Can't access Wegner's original publication. Sources do not seem to be consistent. See post by @j-ryan.

Answer (score 2):

R.e. @fidbc's answer: the bound for the case where $\Delta \geq 8$ has been improved to $\frac{3}{2}\Delta(1+o(1))$ [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.8097&rep=rep1&type=pdf).